# Is there some way to use printf to print a horizontal list of decrementing hex digits in NASM assembly on Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I essentially want to write a program that takes F and decrements it until its 0, displaying the results like : F E D C B A 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0. I specifically have to use a loop to write these out, i can't just say "db 'F E D C B A 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1' , 10, 0". Since I can't use system calls to print (write) hex digits I abandoned that way of thinking. Wherever I go I'm told to use printf since it doesn't require a conversion from number to character. However, printf seems to require a parameter that's usually something along the lines of "db '%x', 10, 0" within a label. That 10 usually being a LF makes it seemingly impossible to write a *horizontal* list and instead writes a *vertical* list which I really don't want.

So I tried to take this program:

```
extern printf
global main

section .data

format_specifier:
  db '%x', 10, 0 ;format specifier for printf with LF

section .text

main:

mov rbx, qword 16

loop1: ;loop to decrement and print number in rsi 

dec rbx
mov rdi, format_specifier
mov rsi, rbx
xor rax, rax
call printf


cmp rbx, qword 0
jne loop1

mov rax, 60
syscall
```

and replace the 10 in the format specifier with 0x20 (the space ASCII) to separate the hex digits as they printed. This, of course, resulted in nothing outputting whatsoever.

I have seen that LF flushes the output buffer and I have tried using fflush to do the same with no avail as seen:

```
extern printf
extern fflush
global main

section .data

format_specifier:
  db '%x', 0x20, 0 ;format specifier for printf with LF

section .text

main:

mov rbx, qword 16

loop1: ;loop to decrement and print number in rsi 

dec rbx
mov rdi, format_specifier
mov rsi, rbx
xor rax, rax
xor rsi, rsi
call fflush
call printf


cmp rbx, qword 0
jne loop1

mov rax, 60
syscall
```

I'm unsure whether it is even the right idea to try and use fflush for my program or if I'm just going in the wrong direction. Please help.

Comment: Just print the numbers first without the line feed and then print a line feed by itself. Also you can use `putchar` so you don't need a format string (but then you need to take care of the hex conversion yourself).

Comment: Ok sorry I probably should have clarified that I have to use a loop of decrements for the number and print them out like that, I can't do "db 'F E D C B A 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1' , 10, 0". Editing my post to make that more clear sorry.

Comment: You can still use the loop. I did not mean to put it as a string constant but that would of course also work :)

Comment: Well my problem is that I can't print anything at all without having to use a line feed, if I do, it will ruin the horizontal part of my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` with the space and then a separate line feed. Also `putchar` is a thing. Furthermore you should keep stack 16 byte aligned and using the exit syscall is bad practice.

A possible solution:

```
extern printf
extern putchar
global main

section .data

format_specifier:
  db '%X', 0x20, 0 ;format specifier for printf with trailing space

section .text

main:
    push rbx ; rbx is callee-saved. Also aligns stack.
    mov ebx, 15 ; 32 bits is enough

loop1: ;loop to decrement and print number in ebx 
    lea rdi, [rel format_specifier] ; use position independent code
    mov esi, ebx
    xor eax, eax ; 32 bit ops zero extend
    call printf wrt ..plt ; PIC
    dec ebx
    jns loop1
    mov edi, 10 ; LF
    call putchar wrt ..plt

    xor eax, eax ; exit code
    pop rbx
    ret
```

Caveat: this will print a space after the final `0`.

Or, you can avoid `printf` altogether:

```
extern putchar
global main

main:
    push rbx ; rbx is callee-saved. Also aligns stack.
    mov ebx, 'F'

loop1: ;loop to decrement and print char in ebx
    mov edi, ebx
    call putchar wrt ..plt ; PIC
    dec ebx
    cmp ebx, '0'
    jb done
    cmp ebx, 'A' - 1
    jne space
    mov ebx, '9'
space:
    mov edi, ' '
    call putchar wrt ..plt
    jmp loop1

done:
    mov edi, 10 ; LF
    call putchar wrt ..plt

    xor eax, eax ; exit code
    pop rbx
    ret
```

Comment: that worked very well, thank you so much!